# Troubleshooting Wine-staging and Yabridge VSTs

Tags: audio, manjaro, wine, troubleshooting, plugin

I'm running two Windows VSTs using Wine-staging 7.15 and Yabridge 4.0.2-1 hosted in Bitwig Studio on Manjaro. The plugins are Arturia Pigments and Novum Granular which both work as expected except for one issue. I cannot access the main menus located in the top left corner of the interface on either device. This means I am unable to access the save/load features. What is strange is if I run Manjaro Gnome from a live USB, the same kernel and the same versions of Wine, Yabridge, Bitwig and the plugins, the menus work. I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting this issue on my installation. Has anyone had similar issues? Can anyone offer any guidance on where to start to identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem, it was the Unite Gnome shell extension causing the issue. Once it was disabled, the menus in all plugins work as expected.